# Nike+ FuelBand (Pedometer) with local analysis software - no personal data in cloud

Tags: network, health.app

I want to buy the **Nike+ FuelBand**, but don't want my information to be in the cloud.

Extracted from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nike+iPod#Online_integration):

> In addition to tracking personal workout statistics, the Nike+ integrates directly with the Nike website. Workout data can be automatically uploaded to the website during an iPod sync with iTunes or through another program via the website's public API. The uploaded information is mostly not personally-identifying, but does also contain some personal statistics such as weight (if configured). Workout data is stored in XML files on the iPod, which has led some web and applications programmers to offer alternatives to the official Nike reports.

So, is there any **OS X** software I can use to have these nice diagrams? And, is it possible to use the Nike+ FuelBand without *syncing* to the cloud?

Comment: Great question - I was initially thinking of looking for something to scrape it as it goes to the cloud, but if someone has cracked the Bluetooth - that would be even easier for us to get "our data".

Comment: The device connects to a computer via USB,. There is hope for third party applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's technically possible, but no apps have so far used the Nike+ Fuelband without using Nike's website. [Hack Nike+ Fuelband](http://hacknikefuelband.com/) tried to make this a reality, but there has been no progress.